# How to display a message box along with the cell number in excel using VBA on saving it

Tags: vba, excel

i want to create a vba code through which i will be able to display message box along with cell number whenever i input a particular value in any cell and save it by pressing ctrl+s means whenever i will input any value in any cell in my excel sheet and save it, it will show a popup message with "value saved in cell A1" like this. kindly help me regarding this

Comment: Homework: Research Workbook events, msgbox and activecell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)
MsgBox "Values saved in cell " & Selection.Address
End Sub
```

The issue with this is that it will only show the selected address when saving the workbook, but I'm sure if nothing else it will point you towards the right direction..

Comment: working great thanks however i made some changes kindly see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)
MsgBox "Values saved in cell " & Replace(Selection.Address, "$", "")
End Sub

Sub Test()

Workbook_AfterSave True

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you add some commentary, explaining what you have done etc.

Comment: i have called workbook_aftersave in  sub test() to run the code & in Sub Workbook_AfterSave previously it was displaying cell value with A$ so i have replaced $ with "  " blank space